# Physically printing a different number for each copy of a pdf (or other format)

Tags: pdf, printing, uniqueidentifier

I would like to know if it's possible to create a pdf file, send it to a print shop, and that each copy once printed has a unique identification number.

For instance, the document would have a fixed content like "Banana". But next to it, there would be a field that gives a different result everytime the document gets printed. Maybe it would be possible to force the printer to print the time when it prints in milliseconds, or any other unique identification? The result I would like to get would be:

Copy #1 : Banana - 42822435

Copy #2 : Banana - 42922998

Copy #3 : Banana - 43059609

etc.

It is possible to have a result like this with a pdf document? I feel like I could get something like that with some code, but I have to go through a print shop. So, I have to be able to just upload a file, and ask them to print multiple copies of it for me.

I hope my question is clear, thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Such functionality would 100% rely on your printer and what they use. It has nothing to do with PDF unless you change and generate a single PDF with 1000 documents and you inject the number. Or you generate 1000 PDFs each with their own number.

Comment: So it's just not possible, right? I thought I'd try it here because sometimes people know stuff I have never heard off.

Comment: I did not say it was impossible. I said you would first need to ask your print service company. Perhaps they have some way of overlaying text onto the PDF. Or as I said, you could generate the PDF with the numbers. It would not be much different if the existing PDF is used as underlay. Both are solutions.

Comment: One Print standard suited for this is PPML which can have reusable content PDF and variable data. Search PPML and discuss with your print company if they can support it.

Comment: Great thank you for your suggestion. The 1000 pages pdf would had been possible but a bit tedious to implement. I'll look into PPML

Comment: With a technology like xsl fo it would be trival

Comment: With the time constraint I have I'll probably go with the long pdf solution. But, for the future I'll look into xsl fo or ppml options. Thank you for your help again. Can you edit your answer to include those (like this I think the question is fully answered for the future)?